# Merge production site's content into staging through database tables

Tags: 7, database

I am working on a major upgrade on my website which includes several new modules being installed, various theme changes, updates on existing modules and a few modules that were uninstalled.

All the changes have been made in the staging site but, in the meantime, content is continuously being added in the production site. Since the staging site was a mirror of the production site (at that time), I was thinking that since the configuration changes that I made are a lot, I could just merge the database tables that are related to content in the staging site and make it my new production site (after some testing that everything works OK of course).

Notice that I have already checked the [Deploy](http://drupal.org/project/deploy) and [Node Export](http://drupal.org/project/node_export) modules but the first one is still in Alpha and the second does not support exporting revisions (which is a critical issue for my site).

My question is: what are the database tables that I should export from the production site in order to transfer all the content (nodes, revisions, profile2 entities, files) from the live to the staging database?

Keep in mind that no structural changes related to entities have been made to either database, so they should be identical.

From a preliminary search, the tables that seem to be relevant are: field_* , node_* , taxonomy_* , url_alias, profile, location*.

Is there something that I' missing here (other tables that I should copy or possibly a better way to do what I'm after)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the [migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate) or [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) modules. I recently used the migrate module with great success, though it does require you to write your own classes.